# why is an error code for a2 not being defined show

Tags: python, python-3.6, nameerror

> find numbers and compares with eachother
>
> to see if they are bigger or smaller.

```
x = input("Your First Capacity? ")
y = input("Your Second Capacity? ")
z = input("Your Required Capacity? ")

x = int(x)
y = int(y)
z = int(z)

if x <= z:
    if y != z:
        if x != z:
            a1 = x
            b1 = y

if y <= z:
    if x != z:
        if y != z:
            a1 = y
            b1 = x
```

> if one number is the same the code dosnt carry on

```
if (x == z) or (y == z):
    print("Required Capasity Already Reached")


a1 = 0
b1 = 0
```

> statements for making a2 = the remaining of a1 for 0-10.

```
if a1 == 0:
    a2 = a1
```

> statements for making b2 = the remaining of b1 from 0-10.

```
if b1 == 0:
    b2 = b1

a1 = a1 - 1
b1 = b1 - 1
```

Why is `print(a2)` returning a `0` intead of `1` if a1 = 3

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is causing you an error because you are using if statements to compare your input to a string, when you have already converted them (your input) into integers. You should instead use

```
if a1 == 1:  # Notice no quotation marks around the number. Important!!
   a2 = a1 - 1
```

because you've used:

```
x = int(x)
y = int(y)
z = int(z)
```

You need to change this  for all if statements.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much, i have been stuck on this for ages

Comment: could you try to answer the new problem please, i edited it

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by your new question, you have to change each if statement back to the way it was, just without the quotation marks.`if a1=0: a2=a1` will only ever return 0 as it's just been given the same value as `a1`, which is 0.

Comment: a1 has been changed to a1 -1, so if a1 was 3, it would be 2. i want then for the if statements to see that and make a2 = 1 so that the (a1-1) + a2 = a1